# ofstream doesn't work when the variable is an attribute

Tags: c++, ofstream

This implementation of ofstream works :

```
bool LinuxSysCall::addNewUser(std::string const &login, std::string const &password) {

    std::ofstream out;
    out.open(DATABASEPATH, std::ios::app);

    if (out.is_open())
    {
        std::string str = login + ":" + password + "\n";
        std::cout << "writing " << str << std::endl;
        out << str;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//The new line is written in the file
```

But when I put my `std::ofstream out` as an attribute of `LinuxSysCall`, it doesn't work anymore (without trowing any exceptions):

```
bool LinuxSysCall::addNewUser(std::string const &login, std::string const &password) {
    this->out.open(DATABASEPATH, std::ios::app);

    if (this->out.is_open())
    {
        std::string str = login + ":" + password + "\n";
        std::cout << "writing " << str << std::endl;
        this->out << str;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//The new line is not written in the file
```

Why ?

Comment: What state was the the stream `out` in before you called `open( ... )` on it?

Comment: probably this->out.is_open() returned false.

Comment: Please don't use `this->` when it's not needed. It's noisy, and it makes you look like a C programmer. <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor of `std::ofstream` calls `close`.  This will flush the text to the file.

If you want to use a member variable (not "attribute") you would need:

```
bool LinuxSysCall::addNewUser(std::string const &login, 
                              std::string const &password) {
    this->out.open(DATABASEPATH, std::ios::app);

    if (this->out.is_open())
    {
        std::string str = login + ":" + password + "\n";
        std::cout << "writing " << str << std::endl;
        this->out << str;
        this->out.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As it stands, using a member variable is much worse than using the local - however, I suspect you *actually* want to pass the open file around amongst many member functions.  If so, you can flush the output with:

```
    this->out << std::flush;
```

without closing it.